# Ionic PayPal Plugin iOS app store uploading issue

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When I'm using the PayPal plugin in my ionic app. During the uploading to the app store, I'm receiving the error of UIWEBVIEW Deprection API. I have tried all possible solutions but still, I didn't resolve the issue. When I removed this plugin from my app. the app is successfully uploaded to the app store. Kindly provide me a possible solution to resolve it. I need to use this plugin in my App.

Comment: What cordova Version you are using?

Comment: cordova 10.0.0v
Ionic 6.12.3v

Comment: And what is your Platform version?

Comment: Bro, Actually I'm not with my mac. but the android version is 9.0.0. Could please tell me the possible solution for ios. I'm stuck from the last two days. Please provide me the possible solution ASAP. Thanks

Comment: You have to Update your Cordova IOS platform Version. then try again.

Comment: Yes I updated it and I'm using the latest IOS platform